# BERT skipping the 1st row of test.tsv when predicting

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I'm running [BERT-Base, Uncased](https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip) pre-trained model on a news classification problem. Most of the core logic for data preparation was copied from [here](https://towardsml.com/2019/09/17/bert-explained-a-complete-guide-with-theory-and-tutorial/). I'm running it on a different dataset though, hence relevant changes have been done. I've 490 news articles, and the train, validation, test data ratios are 405 : 45 : 40. These datasets are present in `train.tsv`, `dev.tsv` and `test.tsv` files in the same dir, all without header. The command I'm using for running the classifier is something like this:

```
python /Users/<username>/Documents/CodeBase/Projects/BERT/run_classifier.py \
--task_name=cola \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--do_predict=true \
--data_dir=/Users/<username>/Desktop/NLP_Learning/Fraud\ detection/BERT \
--vocab_file=./vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=./bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=./bert_model.ckpt \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--train_batch_size=32 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--num_train_epochs=3.0 \
--output_dir=/Users/<username>/Desktop/NLP_Learning/Fraud\ detection/BERT_Model_Pretrained/output \
--do_lower_case=True
```

Now, even though the training and prediction finishes, trouble is the generated `test_results.tsv` file contains only 39 rows, which should have been 40. By the looks of it, it seems row-0 of `test.tsv` is somehow getting skipped. What am I missing here? I've checked all three input data files, and they all contain proper number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the data formats for `cola` tasks are very specific. It requires 3 files `train.tsv`, `dev.tsv` and `test.tsv`, for training-set, development/validation set and test set respectively.

Coming to the data-formats in each TSV files.
`train.tsv` and `dev.tsv` have same format:

`id    class_label    segment    text`

and both `train.tsv` and `dev.tsv` should **not** have headers.

However, coming to the `test.tsv`, below is the format:

`id    text`  (Note that you should not provide the labels or the segment columns).

More **importantly**: `test.tsv` **should have a header**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed the header in the `test.tsv`, which is why it was giving me one less prediction.

Comment: Yes, the format mainly comes from the COLA task's default files,.. https://nyu-mll.github.io/CoLA/